# 'dict' object does not support indexing python flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a web app that has a search button that searches a postgres table.

I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing

My code is as follows:

> app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

app = Flask(__name__)

db_string = "postgres://xi:x@x:5432/xx"

db = create_engine(db_string)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        jn = request.form['jobnumber']
        result_set = db.execute("SELECT cost FROM public.options where optionno = (f'%jn%')").fetchall()
        return render_template('main.html', test=result_set, jn=jn)
    else:
        return render_template('main.html')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

and my HTML is:

> main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>xxx</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
</head>

<body>
<p>xxx</p>

<form method="POST" id="jobnumber">
    <input name="jobnumber" type="textbox" placeholder="jobnumber">
</form>

<table> 

<td>
       {{test}}

</td>


</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You must absolutely not use string interpolation to form SQL queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has a text function for converting string to sqlalchemy text object which appears to correctly escape the SQL for you.

You need to import
`from sqlalchemy import text'

And you need to remove f from the query and also change `=` to `like` or `ilike`

i.e.
`res = db.execute(text("SELECT cost FROM public.options where optionno like  ('%jn%')")).fetchall()`

Comment: Hi Mahesh, thanks for your reply. I've a new issue now, i have the error code:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: real ~~ unknown
LINE 1: SELECT cost FROM public.options where optionno like  ('%jn%'...
                                                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
 [SQL: "SELECT cost FROM public.options where optionno like  ('%%jn%%')"] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the datatype of `optionno` column in your postgresql database, if it **real** or **integer** then the query gives error, `optionno` is in **character** type not a **number**

Comment: yes optionno is type 'real' in postgres, it's basically a column full of numbers and i'm searching for a number

Comment: you need to cast real to character your new query is `db.execute(text("SELECT cost FROM public.options where cast(optionno AS VARCHAR) like  ('%jn%')")).fetchall()`

Comment: thanks mahesh, that worked but it's not returning any data, just []  any ideas

Comment: change your code as `db.execute(text("SELECT cost FROM public.options where optionno like  ('%{}%')".format(jn))).fetchall()`

Comment: Please do not do what @mastermindr suggested in the above comment, as it is open to SQL injection. In other words never format values to queries. Use your library's or driver's placeholders. In case of SQLA: `db.execute(text("SELECT ... WHERE optionno LIKE :jn"), {"jn": f"%{jn}%"})`